# Failed to process package 'rviz':

Tags: ros, rviz, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   signals
--   system
--   thread
-- Eigen found (include: /opt/local/include/eigen3)
-- checking for module 'OGRE'
--   package 'OGRE' not found
Package OGRE was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OGRE.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OGRE' found
-- OGRE_PLUGIN_PATH=
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/Trung/ros_catkinws/devel_isolated/rviz
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /Users/Trung/ros_catkinws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /Users/Trung/ros_catkinws/install_isolated
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /Users/Trung/ros_catkinws/build_isolated/rviz/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.73
CMake Error at /Users/Trung/ros_catkinws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "map_msgs" with any
  of the following names:

    map_msgsConfig.cmake
    map_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "map_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "map_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "map_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:39 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
<== Failed to process package 'rviz': 
  Command '/Users/Trung/ros_catkinws/install_isolated/env.sh make cmake_check_build_system' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77071/failed-to-process-package-%27rviz%27:/) by [fti](https://answers.ros.org/users/6491/fti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you are trying to compile rviz from source. Why? You appear to be missing the map_msgs package, upon which rviz depends. There are 29 rviz dependencies, and you probably need them all.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2019-10-30**:
how can i do this? please help!